# Confluence: show {children} in table

Tags: confluence

Is there a way to display {children} in a table in a way that they all sit withing a column, one per row?

Say, I have subpages a, b and c, and want them show in a table with page name, author and something else:

|a|Denis|40|

|b|Alex|43|

|c|Unknown|2|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the reporting plugin

checkout
http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/AtlassianPlugins/Reporting+Plugin

for instance use following config

```
{report-table}

{local-reporter:page:children}
{text-sort:page:title}
{local-reporter}

{report-column:title=Title}{report-info:page:title}{report-column}
{report-column:title=Author}{report-info:page:creator}{report-column}

{report-table}
```

Quite a bit of fun using it, once that you get going.

Francis

Answer (score 0):

You could also use {[metadata-report](https://comalatech.jira.com/wiki/display/META/Metadata-report+macro)}

```
    {metadata-report:Page,Author}
```

{metadata-report} is used to display metadata stored on pages using the [Metadata plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.andya.confluence.plugins.metadata) and can also be used to dislay content properties including: `Page,Author,Last Changed By,Last Time Changed,Date,Time,Time Created,Posted,Space,Parent`

You can also set the root page to start from and pull all of the basic page metadata out into a table. Example:

```
    {metadata-report:Page,Author,Last Changed By,Last Time Changed,Date,Time,Time Created,Posted,Space,Parent|root=somepagewithchildren|pages=@descendants}
```

This can be wrapped in `{table-filter}` and `{table-plus}` macros for sorting.

```
{table-filter:userfilter=Page,Author,Time Created} 
{table-plus:columnTypes=S,S,D"dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm"} 
{metadata-report:Page,Author,Time Created} 
{table-plus} 
{table-filter}
```